# Theorem on separable differential equations: is the continuity of $Y'$ necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I was reviewing some theorems on differential equations when I came to this theorem on separable d.e. on *Calculus I* by Apostol :

> Let $y = Y(x)$ be any solution of the separable differential equation
> $$A(y)y' = Q(x) $$
> **such that $Y'$ is continuous on an open interval $I$**. Assume that both $Q$ and the composite function $A \circ Y$ are continuous on $I$. Let $G$ be any primitive of $A$, that is, any function such that $G' =A$. Then the solution $Y$ satisfies the implicit formula
> $$ G(y) = \int Q(x) dx + C $$
> for some constant $C$. Conversely, if $y$ satisfies the above formula then $y$ is a solution of the differential equation.

and the proof goes like this:

> Since $Y$ is a solution of the differential equation we must have
>
> $$A[Y(x)] Y'(x) = Q(x)$$
>
> for each $x$ in $I$. Since $G'= A$, this equation becomes
>
> $$G'[Y(x)]Y'(x) = Q(x)$$
>
> but, by the chain rule, the left member is the derivative of the
> composite $G \circ Y$. Therefore $G \circ Y$ is a primitive of $Q$,
> wich means that
>
> $$G[Y(x)] = \int Q(x) dx + C $$
>
> for some constant $C$. This is the relation we were looking for.
> Conversely, if $y = Y(x)$ satisfies the above formula, differentiation
> gives us the initial differential equation.

---

My question regards the assumption on the continuity of $Y'$: while I understand the continuity assumption on $Q$ and $A \circ Y$ which basically makes the two functions integrable, I don't get where it is used the continuity of $Y'$ in the given proof. Can it be removed?

Also, I recognized that, given the continuity assumptions on $Q$ and $A \circ Y$ and the separable d.e $A(y)y' = Q(x) $, we are almost there in the sense that $y'$ needs to be continuous **if** $A(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$. So I thought that maybe it is not an assumption but a necessary condition, but anyway $A(y)$ can be zero for some $y$ so I don't know if this is so.

**Edit :**

At the start of the section, outside of the theorem, it is written that we start with $y' = Q(x)R(y)$ and then when $R(y) \neq 0$ we can rewrite it as the d.e. in the theorem.

So $A(y) = \frac{1}{R(y)}$ which means $A(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$ for which it is defined. This makes me think that the second interpretation is the right one because,  given all of this, $y'$ has to be continuous. Is this the meaning?

Comment: It's kind of a consequence of the other hypothesis. If $A$, $Y$, the composition of those two, and $Q$ are al continuous, then $Y'$ has to be continuous on $I$. If you happen to 
solve an ODE where any of the functions has a discontinuity, you would always find open intervals where they are all continuous and thus integrable.

Comment: thanks @Luciano, I "roughly" agree with you, specifically: are you saying that $ A(y)≠0$
for all $y$ (letting this be possible, without considering the edit section) is not necessary to assure the continuity of Y′ besides all other assumptions? Or are you saying avoiding those points where $A(y) \neq 0$ I will anyway find an interval?

Comment: I mean the latter. We usually restrict the integration to an interval where "everything works" and all conditions are satisfied, no denominators are zero, no multiplication times zero, etc. But then we analize if the restrictions we've made left out any possible solutions. For example, consider the classic separable ODE $y'=y-1$, where clearly you need $y \neq 1$ in order to divide by that factor and then integrate in a valid open interval. But then, if you analize the constant function $y=1$ that we left out (looking at the original form of the ODE), it is indeed another solution.

Comment: I totally agree, thanks for the explaination. Anyway, the wording of the theorem was really strange